# How to select records where no linked records in another table are null?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL:

```
SELECT tournaments_blg.tournament_id_blg
FROM matches_blg  LEFT JOIN tournaments_blg ON tournaments_blg.tournament_id_blg = matches_blg.tournament_id_blg
WHERE matches_blg.match_id_op IS NULL
GROUP BY tournaments_blg.tournament_id_blg
```

This selects all `tournaments_blg.tournament_id_blg` where any one of `matches_blg.match_id_op` is `NULL`.

How would I only select all `tournaments_blg.tournament_id_blg` if ALL the `matches_blg.match_id_op` are `NULL`?

Comment: Provide some sample data with your desired output in table format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT tb.tournament_id_blg
FROM tournaments_blg tb
LEFT JOIN matches_blg mb ON tb.tournament_id_blg = mb.tournament_id_blg 
                        AND mb.match_id_op IS NOT NULL
WHERE mb.tournament_id_blg IS NULL
```

or

```
SELECT tb.tournament_id_blg
FROM tournaments_blg tb
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM matches_blg mb 
                   WHERE tb.tournament_id_blg = mb.tournament_id_blg 
                     AND mb.match_id_op IS NOT NULL )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

`SELECT tournaments_blg.tournament_id_blg FROM matches_blg  WHERE matches_blg.match_id_op NOT IN (Select tournaments_blg from tournaments_blg )`